# Get Cart products id on checkout WooCommerce page, to display product images

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product

I'm using woocommerce on a site I'm working on and I want to display the current product thumbnail at the top of the checkout page, so the user could take a look at what his going to buy.

However I can't find any way to do so.

The closest I got, is to use **`WC::cart->get_cart()`**, but this outputs a list of all products.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please include more code to give context about your question.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow, what you really want? the checkout page only have the products that are in your cart.
Clear the question please

Comment: @LoicTheAztec you right, I was a little busy the past two days. Your solution works and I accepted the answer, thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it's possible writing a custom function.

To display those images at the beginning of checkout page just after your header's theme, use this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'displays_cart_products_feature_image');
function displays_cart_products_feature_image() {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if(!empty($product)){
            // $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
            echo $product->get_image();

            // to display only the first product image uncomment the line below
            // break;
        }
    }
}
```

*This code snippet goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

You can change the images properties adding some options in [get_image()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_image) function.

**This code is tested and fully functional**

---

**OTHER USAGES - You can also use it:**

1). With the following others **checkout** WooCommerce **hooks** *(replacing the first line in the snippet code with one of this)*:

• Before customer details:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'displays_cart_products_feature_image');
```

• After customer details:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details', 'displays_cart_products_feature_image');
```

• Before order review:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'displays_cart_products_feature_image');
```

2). Directly inside your [woocommerce templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) *(this snippet code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme)*:

```
function displays_cart_products_feature_image() {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if(!empty($product)){
            // $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
            echo $product->get_image();

            // to display only the first product image uncomment the line below
            // break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will just paste one of this inside the [template file](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/):

- inside HTML code: `<?php displays_cart_products_feature_image(); ?>`
- inside PHP code: `displays_cart_products_feature_image();`

Reference:

- [Class WC_Cart | WooCommerce 2.1.x Code Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html)
- [Class WC_Product | WooCommerce 3.x Code Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)
- [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: `$cart_item['data']` is already having `WC_Product` object, So no need to re instantiate again.

Comment: @rram Yes you are right, Thanks… I have updated the code  *(This was an old answer)*

Comment: Cool +1, I too not sure from when(which version) WooCommerce started giving product instance in `$cart_item['data']`

Comment: @rram It was already working 2 years ago, but I just made a small mistake here… Thanks again :)