# Product photos appear above list of products at Checkout (Wordpress/WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On my Wordpress website, using WooCommerce, on the Checkout page, I am seeing the photos appear above the list of products at Checkout. How do I make them appear IN the list of products, as shown?

[image]

This is what I have at the moment:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'displays_cart_products_feature_image');
function displays_cart_products_feature_image() {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $item = $cart_item['data'];
        if(!empty($item)){
            $product = new WC_product($item->id);
            // $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
            echo $product->get_image();

            // to display only the first product image uncomment the line bellow
            // break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is related to [Get Cart products id on checkout WooCommerce page, to display product images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798888/get-cart-products-id-on-checkout-woocommerce-page-to-display-product-images/45650633#45650633).

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That depends... how are you coding it?

Comment: Sorry, should've added that. It's now in the original post.

Comment: it's because your hook is `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review` the table is the order review

Comment: How then do I add each product's photo in each product row in the order review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review`, we can use `woocommerce_cart_item_name` filter like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'displays_cart_products_feature_image', 10, 2 );
function displays_cart_products_feature_image( $cart_item_name, $cart_item ) {

    return ( is_checkout() ) ? $cart_item['data']->get_image() . $cart_item_name : $cart_item_name;

}
```

what this will do is put the image before the product name. Something like this image below:

[image: reigelgallarde.me]

Still not what we need right? Yes but it's the closest thing we can get. And just some CSS will fixed the problem.

```
.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table .cart_item .product-name img {
    float: right;
}
```

Will look like this below:
[image]

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Comment: It kinda work, but can you look at the last screenshot in my original post? I can't seem to get it on the right side despite using the css code in custom.css.

Comment: I'm​ not sure what's wrong.. because I can't see your theme's css rules..